# Radix sort failing

Tags: sorting, radix-sort, radix

I have following string which I have to sort using Radix sort:
1, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 3.2, 3.2.2, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.3, 7.1.1, 7.3, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.3, 9.4, 4, 4.1, 4.3, 4.3, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 5.1.2, 5.3, 10, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2

I am using LSD based Radix sort and below are the result after every pass:

**After first pass:**
1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 3.2, 6.3, 7.3, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.3, 9.4, 4, 4.1, 4.3, 4.3, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 5.3, 10, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 7.1.1, 3.2.2, 5.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5

**After second pass:**
1, 4, 10, 4.1, 9.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 7.1.1, 5.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 3.2, 2.2, 9.2, 11.2, 11.2, 3.2.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 9.3, 9.3, 7.3, 2.3, 4.3, 4.3, 5.3, 6.3, 2.4, 9.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7

**After third pass:**
1, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 3.2, 3.2.2, 4, 4.3, 4.3, 4.1, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 5.3, 5.1.2, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.1, 6.3, 7.1.1, 7.3, 9.4, 9.3, 9.2, 9.1, 9.3, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 10, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2

As you can see the final sorted string is not correct. I am having hard time figuring out what am I missing. Or is the algorithm failing for this use case.

EDIT1: Putting the code

The code is in the native language(BML) og a CPQ tool (BigMachines)

---

```
sortedBySubGroupMELStr = "";
sortedBySubGroupAndByCPCMELStr = "";
melStringTemp = returnString;
melArrTemp = split(melStringTemp,rowDelim);
i=0;
for val in melArrTemp{
j=0;
    for val1 in melArrTemp{
    if(j > i){
            rowdataArr = split(melArrTemp[i],colDelim);
            rowdataArr1 = split(melArrTemp[j],colDelim);
            pos = split(rowdataArr[27],".");
            pos1 = split(rowdataArr1[27],".");
            if(pos[2] == "" and pos1[2] == ""){
                break;
            }
            if(pos1[2] == "" and pos[2] <> ""){
                    temp = melArrTemp[i];
                    melArrTemp[i] = melArrTemp[j];
                    melArrTemp[j] = temp;
            }
            if(pos1[2] <> "" and pos[2] <> ""){
                if(isnumber(pos1[2]) and isnumber(pos[2])){
                    if(atoi(pos1[2]) < atoi(pos[2])){
                        temp = melArrTemp[i];
                        melArrTemp[i] = melArrTemp[j];
                        melArrTemp[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        j = j + 1;
    }
    i = i + 1;
}

print "after first pass";
for val in melArrTemp{
    tempVal = split(val,colDelim);
    print tempVal[27];
}

i=0;
for val in melArrTemp{
j=0;
    for val1 in melArrTemp{
    if(j > i){
            rowdataArr = split(melArrTemp[i],colDelim);
            rowdataArr1 = split(melArrTemp[j],colDelim);
            pos = split(rowdataArr[27],".");
            pos1 = split(rowdataArr1[27],".");
            if(pos[1] == "" and pos1[1] == ""){
                break;
            }
            if(pos1[1] == "" and pos[1] <> ""){
                    temp = melArrTemp[i];
                    melArrTemp[i] = melArrTemp[j];
                    melArrTemp[j] = temp;
            }
            if(pos1[1] <> "" and pos[1] <> ""){
                if(isnumber(pos1[1]) and isnumber(pos[1])){
                    if(atoi(pos1[1]) < atoi(pos[1])){
                        temp = melArrTemp[i];
                        melArrTemp[i] = melArrTemp[j];
                        melArrTemp[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        j = j + 1;
    }
    i = i + 1;
}


    print "after second pass";
for val in melArrTemp{
    tempVal = split(val,colDelim);
    print tempVal[27];
}

i=0;
for val in melArrTemp{
j=0;
    for val1 in melArrTemp{
    if(j > i){
            rowdataArr = split(melArrTemp[i],colDelim);
            rowdataArr1 = split(melArrTemp[j],colDelim);
            pos = split(rowdataArr[27],".");
            pos1 = split(rowdataArr1[27],".");
            if(pos[0] == "" and pos1[0] == ""){
                break;
            }
            if(pos1[0] == "" and pos[0] <> ""){
                    temp = melArrTemp[i];
                    melArrTemp[i] = melArrTemp[j];
                    melArrTemp[j] = temp;
            }
            if(pos1[0] <> "" and pos[0] <> ""){
                if(isnumber(pos1[0]) and isnumber(pos[0])){
                    if(atoi(pos1[0]) < atoi(pos[0])){
                        temp = melArrTemp[i];
                        melArrTemp[i] = melArrTemp[j];
                        melArrTemp[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        j = j + 1;
    }
    i = i + 1;
}

    print "after third pass";

for val in melArrTemp{
    melArrVal = split(val,colDelim);
    print melArrVal[27];

}
```

---

```
***

***WHERE:***

**colDelim** = ^N^

**rowDelim** = ###

**returnString** = H222790-1^N^ASSEMBLY,GUIDE BASE,TEMPORARY,MUDMAT,37-1/64 ID,W/ LATCH RING GROOVE W/ADAPTER RING. 12 FOOT SQ. FOOT PRINT. NOTES: 3. STENCIL: P/N H222790-1 (REV) SER. NO VETCO GRAY (COM) 4. IF MUDMAT NEEDS TO BE RELEASED FROM LATCH, USE P/N H50710-6 (QTY. 12) IN THE 3/4 IN. THREADED HOLES WEIGHT: 8,100 LBS.^N^26553.03^N^Y^N^USD^N^26553.03^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^Mudmat!@!<<BLT>> 12 ft. x 12 ft. square base!@!<<BLT>> Helps support the conductor string on the sea floor!@!<<BLT>> May be used to support conductor in moon pool (Capacity determined by beam spacing)!@!<<BLT>> Installed with minimal manual intervention!@!<<BLT>> Locates top of housing relative to sea floor!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W82^N^1^N^1^N^8100^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H57435-15^N^LANDING SUB,MUDMAT LATCH,NOM. 36 X 2.0 WALL W/REACTION RING AND HYDRATE SEALS, INCLUDES SPACER BLOCK F/ LATCH RING (8630 - 95KSI) NOTES: DIMENSIONS: ( A ) DIA. = 32 WEIGHT: 2,140 LBS. (CALC)^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^36" Mudmat Latch Sub!@!<<BLT>> Positions mudmat in the conductor string!@!<<BLT>> Provides hydrate seal between the conductor and the mudmat!@!Min. I. D.: 31.3 in.!@!Weld Prep: 36" x 2 in. on both ends!@!Material: 8630 95 KSI!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W83^N^2^N^2.1.3^N^2140^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###201787-20^N^RAW-PIPE,WELDED, 36.000 NOM DIA, 36.000 OD, 2.000 WALL, MATERIAL PER API 5L,GRX65,65KSI,NO VGS^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^36" LP Housing Extension Joint Pipe!@!<<BLT>> 36" x 2" wall (726.24 #/Ft.) API 5L GR X-65 Pipe!@!<<BLT>> Approximately 40 ft. OAL!@!<<BLT>> Two (2) Landing Pads and two (2) Lift Eyes!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W84^N^2^N^2.1.4^N^^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H32442-1^N^CONNECTOR-TUBULAR PART, RL-2HCX PIN, ASSEMBLY, 36.000, 2.000 WALL, HIGH CAPACITY, R.H, 95 KSI (8630),VGS 2.6.1 WELD PREP, WITH 4 ANTI-ROTATION FEATURES. WEIGHT: 908 LBS. (INCL. PROTECTOR) DIMENSIONS: DIM: A = (2.00) NOMINAL WP DIM: B = (2.015) ACTUALWP DIM: C = (32.00) ID NOTES: 2. SEE H32440-1 FOR MATING BOX CONNECTOR.^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^36" LP Housing Extension Joint Connector!@!<<BLT>> RL-2HCX Pin (down) w/ thread protector!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W85^N^2^N^2.1.5^N^908^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57720-202^N^WELLHEAD HSG PART, BALL VALVE ASSY, 31 IN. LONG, 4 INCH NPT FULL PORT VALVE WITH ROV HANDLE, WITH WECO UNION AND PIPE NIPPLES. WEIGHT: 116 LBS. (EST.)^N^2148.3^N^Y^N^USD^N^2148.3^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^4" Ball Valve Assemblies!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W86^N^2^N^2.2^N^116^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H57720-206^N^WELLHEAD HOUSING PART, MS-700, PLUG, PIPE, 4 IN. NPT, SPECIAL FLUSH TYPE, W/ 1.25 IN. INTERNAL HEX. WEIGHT: 5.8 LBS. (PRO/E)^N^534.14^N^Y^N^USD^N^534.14^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^4'' NPT Pipe Plugs of 0 Units^N^^N^^N^W87^N^2^N^2.3^N^6^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H57720-101^N^SSWE HOUSING PART, SLOPE INDICATOR ASSY, 0-2 DEG., ALL PLASTIC BULLSEYE, ADJUSTABLE,WITH 1-8UNC BOLTS NOTES: 1. STANDARD 4.50 X 2.50 BOLT PATTERN WITH 1 IN. BOLTS AND .50 DIA. ALIGNMENT PINS. WEIGHT: 86 LBS.^N^2349.37^N^Y^N^USD^N^2349.37^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^Bullseye!@!<<BLT>> 0-2 DEG slope level indicator!@!<<BLT>> Complete with bracket for mounting on Ball Valve Sub!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W88^N^2^N^2.4^N^86^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H50780-2^N^CASING HGR,MS-700, 26.000, 1000 PSI MWP, SHALLOW FLOW, W/CAM PROFILE, LOCKDOWN RING, AND HI-INTEG SEAL, W/ 26.000 X .750 WELD PREP DOWN WEIGHT = 1100 (EST)^N^18375.83^N^Y^N^USD^N^18375.83^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^26" Casing Hanger!@!<<BLT>> Mandrel style hanger!@!<<BLT>> Upper running profile accepts CAM tool!@!Weld Prep: 26" x 0.75 in. on both ends!@!Min I.D.: 24.255 in.!@!Max O.D.: 30.679 in.!@!Material: 4130 95KSI!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W89^N^3^N^3.2^N^1100^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###A30334-9^N^CONNECTOR-TUBULAR,RL-4S PIN, 26.000, .750,BW,RH, 70 KSI,C/W (VES 2.6.1) BW PREP,4 CUTOUTS AT 90 DEGAPART^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W90^N^3^N^3.2.2^N^175^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57106-3^N^CASING HGR,MS-700,18.75/10K X 13.375,10000 PSIMSP, WITH TAPERED SEAL POCKET AND NO THREAD PROFILE DOWN,NACE MR-01-75 NOTES: A = 12.280 1. STRESSLESS STAMP: H57106-3 (REV) CSG HGR, 13.375/10K MS-700 SER NO ______________________ VETCO GRAY, (COUNTRY OF MFG.) (ITEM #2 NOT SHOWN ON DRAWING) 3. THD FORM = NO THREAD DOWN CLASSIFICATION OF CHARACTERISTICS PER EHB PART III DOC. 4.3.7. CATAGORY 1: NONE (API 17D REQUIREMENT) CATAGORY 2: OD. 16.823, OD. 17.230, OD. 14.45, OD. 18.592 ID. 13.615, ID. 14.088, ID. 13.253 CATAGORY 3: ALL OTHER DIMENSIONS.^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^13.375" Casing Hanger!@!<<BLT>> Designed to API 17D (PSL 3)!@!<<BLT>> Temperature qualified to 250°!@!<<BLT>> Casing Load: 1,000,000 lbs!@!<<BLT>> Standard Nominal ID: 12.320 in.!@!Inlay: NONE!@!MWP: 10 KSI!@!Max O.D.: 18.592 in.!@!Blank Thread I.D. : null in.!@!Thread Type: NO THREAD ( LB/FT) !@!Material: 8630 85 KSI!@!<<BLT>> Casing hanger capacities are thread dependent, some premium threads may reduce hanger capacities below standard ratings!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W91^N^6^N^6.1.1^N^0^N^12.28^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57007-3^N^CASING HGR,MS-700, 18.750 X 13.375, 10000 PSI MSP, WITH TAPERED SEAL POCKET AND 13.375 BLANK BTM BOX DOWN,NACE MR-01-75^N^8256.57^N^Y^N^USD^N^8256.57^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^13.375" Casing Hanger!@!<<BLT>> Designed to API 17D (PSL 3)!@!<<BLT>> Temperature qualified to 250°!@!<<BLT>> Casing Load: 1,000,000 lbs!@!<<BLT>> Standard Nominal ID: 12.320 in.!@!Inlay: NONE!@!MWP: 10 KSI!@!Max O.D.: 18.592 in.!@!Blank Thread I.D. : 12 in.!@!Thread Type: NO THREAD ( LB/FT) !@!Material: 8630 85 KSI!@!<<BLT>> Casing hanger capacities are thread dependent, some premium threads may reduce hanger capacities below standard ratings!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W92^N^6^N^6.1.1^N^0^N^12.32^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H57900-100^N^CASING HANGER SUBASSY, MS-700, BODY, 18.750 X 13.375 NOMINAL, FIRST POSITION, FOR 15K WELLHEAD, BLANK BOTTOM DOWN, 13.50 IN. HANGER STACKUP SYSTEM, 3 IN. EXTENDED OAL, NACE MR-01-75. WEIGHT: 631 LBS (PRO-E)^N^10243.99^N^Y^N^USD^N^10243.99^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^13.375" Casing Hanger!@!<<BLT>> Designed to API 17D (PSL 3)!@!<<BLT>> Temperature qualified to 250°!@!<<BLT>> Casing Load: 1,000,000 lbs!@!<<BLT>> Standard Nominal ID: 12.320 in.!@!Inlay: NONE!@!MWP: 10 KSI!@!Max O.D.: 18.592 in.!@!Blank Thread I.D. : 12 in.!@!Thread Type: NO THREAD ( LB/FT) !@!Material: 8630 85 KSI!@!<<BLT>> Casing hanger capacities are thread dependent, some premium threads may reduce hanger capacities below standard ratings!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W93^N^6^N^6.1.1^N^631^N^12^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H57902-100^N^CASING HANGER SUBASSY, MS-700, BODY, 18.750 X 13.375 NOMINAL, FIRST POSITION, FOR 15K WELLHEAD, BLANK BOTTOM DOWN, 13.50 IN. HANGER STACKUP SYSTEM, 3 IN. EXTENDED OAL, NACE MR-01-75. WEIGHT: 631 LBS (PRO-E) NOTES: 1. HANGER USED WITH 13.375 (T AND COR INTEGRAL) CASING THRU 14.00/14.25 CASING (INTEGRAL ONLY). 2. MANUFACTURE PER DRAWING H57900-100^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^13.375" Casing Hanger!@!<<BLT>> Designed to API 17D (PSL 3)!@!<<BLT>> Temperature qualified to 250°!@!<<BLT>> Casing Load: 1,000,000 lbs!@!<<BLT>> Standard Nominal ID: 12.320 in.!@!Inlay: NONE!@!MWP: 10 KSI!@!Max O.D.: 18.592 in.!@!Blank Thread I.D. : 12 in.!@!Thread Type: NO THREAD ( LB/FT) !@!Material: 8630 85 KSI!@!<<BLT>> Casing hanger capacities are thread dependent, some premium threads may reduce hanger capacities below standard ratings!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W94^N^6^N^6.1.1^N^631^N^12^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57028-1^N^ANNULUS SEAL, MS-1, 18.750, 15000 RWP^N^4130.29^N^Y^N^USD^N^4130.29^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^MS-1 Seal!@!<<BLT>> 15000 PSI MWP!@!<<BLT>> Weight set lockdown!@!<<BLT>> Metal to Metal sealing!@!<<BLT>> 750,000 MM lbs. of lockdown capacity!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W95^N^6^N^6.3^N^91^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H57940-100^N^CASING HANGER PART, MS-700, BODY, 18.750 X 9.625 NOMINAL, UPPER POSITION, BLANK BOTTOM DOWN, 13.50 IN. HANGER STACKUP SYSTEM, NACE MR-01-75. WEIGHT: 531 LBS (PRO/E) NOTES: 1. HANGER USED WITH 9.625 (T AND C OR INTEGRAL) CASING THRU 10.00 CASING (INTEGRAL ONLY). 2. ITEM 2 NOT SHOWN ON DRAWING.^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^9.625" Casing Hanger!@!<<BLT>> Designed to API 17D (PSL 3)!@!<<BLT>> Temperature qualified to 250°!@!<<BLT>> Casing Load: 1,000,000 lbs!@!<<BLT>> Standard Nominal ID: 12.320 in.!@!Inlay: NONE!@!MWP: 15 KSI!@!Max O.D.: 18.592 in.!@!Blank Thread I.D. : 8.25 in.!@!Thread Type: NO THREAD ( LB/FT) Q-125!@!Material: 8630 85 KSI!@!<<BLT>> Casing hanger capacities are thread dependent, some premium threads may reduce hanger capacities below standard ratings!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W96^N^7^N^7.1.1^N^531^N^8.25^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57028-1^N^ANNULUS SEAL, MS-1, 18.750, 15000 RWP^N^4130.29^N^Y^N^USD^N^4130.29^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^MS-1 Seal!@!<<BLT>> 15000 PSI MWP!@!<<BLT>> Weight set lockdown!@!<<BLT>> Metal to Metal sealing!@!<<BLT>> 750,000 MM lbs. of lockdown capacity!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W97^N^7^N^7.3^N^91^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H57636-1^N^WEAR BUSHING, MS-700,18.750,BRRNSP, FOR USE WITH MS-700 PLUG TOOL FOR SPEAR 15 CATCH DIA WITH PROVISION FOR BIT RUN AND RETRIEVAL  FOR STANDARD 3 HGR HOUSING WEIGHT: 2,100 LBS. (CALC) USE WITH TOOL (H56616), (H56615) THIS CAN NOT BE TESTED WITH THE WEAR R AND R BUSHING TEST TOOL ITEM 16 NOT SHOWN IN DRAWING, THEY GO IN THE .750-10UNC LIFT EYE HOLES LOCATED ON THE BODY.^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^18.75" Wellhead MS-700 Bit Run Retrieval NSP NSP (Nominal Seat Protector)!@!<<BLT>> Installed in 18.75" HP Housing prior to running 13.375" Casing Hanger!@!<<BLT>> Used to protect I.D. of 18.75" HP Housing!@!<<BLT>> Using the BRNSP running tool. operator can run wear bushing during the first BHA run and then later retrieve the NSP on a subsequent BHA run with a BRNSP running and retrieving tool!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W98^N^9^N^9.5^N^2100^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57534-1^N^WEAR BUSHING, MS-700,18.750 X 13.375 FOR USE PLUG TOOL, FOR SPEAR 15 CATCH DIAMETER WITH PROVISION FOR BIT RUN AND RETRIEVAL  (WBBRRT) USE WITH TOOL H56616 OR H56615 (12-1/4 BIT) THIS CAN NOT BE TESTED WITH THE WEAR R AND R BUSHING TEST TOOL ITEM 15 NOT SHOWN IN DRAWING, THEY GO IN THE .750-10UNC LIFT EYE HOLES LOCATED ON THE BODY.^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^13.375" Wear Bushing!@!<<BLT>> Used to protect I.D. of 18.75" / 13.375" HP Housing!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W99^N^9^N^9.6^N^1454^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57535-1^N^WEAR BUSHING, MS-700,18.750 X 9.625 FOR USE WITH SERIES 700 ISOLATION TEST TOOL AND PLUG TOOL, FOR SPEAR 15 CATCH DIAMETER WITH PROVISION FOR BIT RUN AND RETRIEVAL  (WBBRRT) USE WITH TOOL H56418-() (8-1/2 BIT) THIS CAN NOT BE TESTED WITH THE ISOLATATION TEST TOOL^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^9.625" Wear Bushing!@!<<BLT>> Used to protect I.D. of 18.75" / 9.625" HP Housing!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W100^N^9^N^9.7^N^1324^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57028-1^N^ANNULUS SEAL, MS-1, 18.750, 15000 RWP^N^4130.29^N^Y^N^USD^N^4130.29^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W101^N^9^N^9.1^N^91^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H59090-1^N^ANNULUS SEAL, MS-700, SG-TPR, 18.750, 15000 PSI MWP AT ASSEMBLY WITH 60 DEG., E-RING ENTRY REWORK^N^33508.31^N^Y^N^USD^N^33508.31^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^18.75" SG-TPR Seal!@!<<BLT>> 15000 PSI MWP!@!<<BLT>> Weight set lockdown!@!<<BLT>> Metal Lipped elastomer!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W102^N^9^N^9.2^N^^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###111053-1^N^GASKET, VX-2, 18.750, STAINLESS STEEL, 15 KSI MWP,^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^VX-2 Gasket STAINLESS STEEL w/N/A inserts!@!<<BLT>> 15 KSI MWP!@!<<BLT>> Metal to Metal sealing!@!<<BLT>> Utilizes increased contact stresses on sealing faces combined with Moly Coating!@!<<BLT>> Qualified under API PSL-4 and PR-2 (Qualified for gas service)!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W103^N^9^N^9.3^N^^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###111227-1^N^GASKET, VX, 18.750-10000 PSI MSP, STAINLESS STEEL WITH HY-CAR INSERTS^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^VX-2 Gasket STAINLESS STEEL w/HY-CAR inserts!@!<<BLT>> 10 KSI MWP!@!<<BLT>> Metal to Metal sealing!@!<<BLT>> Utilizes increased contact stresses on sealing faces combined with Moly Coating!@!<<BLT>> Qualified under API PSL-4 and PR-2 (Qualified for gas service)!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W104^N^9^N^9.3^N^95^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H288500-1^N^CORROSION CAP,WELLHEAD ABANDONMENT, 18.750,LEAF SPRING RETENTION FOR H-4 WELLHEAD,HAS TWO RUNNING/LIFT PINS, W/HORIZONAL ROV STAB, P/N H50462-1 ROV HOT STAB IS USED TO INJECT OIL DIM A = 55.00^N^14901.44^N^Y^N^USD^N^14901.44^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^18.75" Wellhead Lightweight Corrosion Cap!@!<<BLT>> Includes upper neck w/ ROV handle!@!<<BLT>> Latch keys secure to H-4 profile and ROV stab to allow fluid injection under cap!@!<<BLT>> Dry weight:260 lbs!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W105^N^9^N^9.4^N^260^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###H277223-9^N^WELLHEAD HSG UNIT,SHALLOW FLOW, 18.750 15,000 PSI MWP, MS-700, 3 HGR, TAPER SOCKETS, VG H-4 MANDREL, CAM STYLE RUNNING TOOL, W/ VX/VT GASKET 54.81 STACK-UP, W/ EXTENSION PIPE AND RL-4S PIN CONNECTION, ONE PIECE HOUSING, W/ ANTI-ROTATION FEATURE WEIGHT: 12,696 LBS. (EST.) DIMENSIONS: A = (551.93 IN) B = (54.81 IN) C = (30.52 IN) D = (.812 IN) WALL E = 480 IN +/- 6 IN F = (6.68 IN) G = (18.25 IN) H = (20.71 IN) 3. ITEM 2, NOT SHOWN ON DRAWING 4. BOTTOM CONNECTION: RL-4S PIN 5. AFTER FABRICATION ISCOMPLETE, PREP FOR SHIPPING PER HTS970020.^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^18.75" HC-1 MS-700 HP Housing Assembly, Including!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W106^N^4^N^4^N^0^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57613-1^N^WELLHEAD HSG ASSY,MS-700,18.750,SHALLOW FLOW, 15,000 PSI MWP,3 HANGER, TAPER SOCKETS, VG H-4 MANDREL, WITH VX/VT GASKET 54.81 STACK-UP, ONE PIECE W/ 6X ANTI-ROTATION KEYS^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^18.75" HC-1 MS-700 HP Housing!@!<<BLT>> Capable of rigid lockdown into 36" MS-700 LP Housing!@!<<BLT>> ID profile for CAM running tool!@!<<BLT>> Designed to API 17D (PSL 3)!@!<<BLT>> Includes anti-rotation keys!@!<<BLT>> Tubing hanger locking profile!@!<<BLT>> Temperature qualified to 250°!@!<<BLT>> Inconel lined VX/VT ring groove!@!Mandrel OD with H-4 profile: 27 in.!@!Max. Bending Capacity: 4MM ft./lbs when used w/ DWHD H-4 Connector!@!MWP: 15000 PSI!@!Hanger Positions: 3!@!Min I.D.: 17.56 in.!@!Weld Prep: 0.812 in.!@!<<BLT>> Material: 8630 80 KSI!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W107^N^4^N^4.1^N^6880^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###191592-102^N^RAW-PIPE,WELDED, 20.000 NOM DIA, 20.000 OD, 0.812 WALL, MATERIAL PER API 5L,GRX56,56KSI,NO VGS^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^18.75" HP Housing Extension Joint!@!<<BLT>> 20" X 0.812" wall (166.40140608 /Ft.) API 5L GR X-56 pipe!@!<<BLT>> Approximately 40 FT OAL!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W108^N^4^N^4.3^N^^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###201047-102^N^RAW-PIPE,WELDED, 20.000 OD, 0.812 WALL, MATERIAL PER API 5L,GRX56,56KSI,NO VGS, SAW, W/STD.WELD PREP PER API 5L SEC7.9.3^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^18.75" HP Housing Extension Joint!@!<<BLT>> 20" X 0.812" wall (166.40140608 /Ft.) API 5L GR X-56 pipe!@!<<BLT>> Approximately 40 FT OAL!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W109^N^4^N^4.3^N^^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###A30248-17^N^CONNECTOR-TUBULAR,RL-4S PIN, 20.000, 0.812,BW,RH, 95 KSI,C/W VGS 2.6.1 BW PREP,DRIVEABLE,C/W 4 ANTI-ROTATION SLOTS^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^<<BLT>> RL-4S PIN" (down) w/ thread protector!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W110^N^4^N^4.4^N^119^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###A30248-19^N^CONNECTOR-TUBULAR,RL-4S PIN, 20.000, 0.812,BW,RH, 95 KSI,C/W VGS 2.6.7 BW PREP,DRIVEABLE,C/W 4 ANTI-ROTATION SLOTS^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^<<BLT>> RL-4S PIN" (down) w/ thread protector!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W111^N^4^N^4.4^N^119^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###A30248-25^N^CONNECTOR-TUBULAR,RL-4S PIN, 20.000, 0.812,BW,RH, 70 KSI,C/W VGS 2.6.1 BW PREP,NONDRIVEABLE, W/4 ANTI-ROTATION SLOTS^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^<<BLT>> RL-4S PIN" (down) w/ thread protector!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W112^N^4^N^4.4^N^119^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###A30248-27^N^CONNECTOR-TUBULAR,RL-4S PIN, 20.000, 0.812,BW,RH, 70 KSI,C/W VGS 2.6.7 BW PREP,NON-DRIVEABLE, W/4 ANTI-ROTATION SLOTS^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^<<BLT>> RL-4S PIN" (down) w/ thread protector!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W113^N^4^N^4.4^N^119^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H32201-38^N^TUBULAR-INTERMEDIATE JT, 20.000 X .812 WALL, RL-4S BOX X PIN, 70 KSI, W/ARF, API 5L-X56 PIPE, 40 FT. LG WEIGHT: 6,940 LBS. PIPE O.D. ............= 20.000 PIPE WALL ............= .812 PIPE MATERIAL ........= API 5L-X56 SAW TOP CONNECTION .......= RL-4S BOX (W/ARF) BOTTOM CONNECTION ....= RL-4S PIN (W/ARF) DIMENSIONS: (A) = 21.50 IN. (B) = 18.25 IN. C = 41 FT. 2-1/2 IN. D = 40 FT. 9 IN. (E) = .812^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^20" Intermediate Joint!@!<<BLT>> 20" X 0.812" (166.40140608#) API 5L X-56 pipe!@!<<BLT>> 40FT Length!@!<<BLT>> RL-4S () BOX UP X PIN DOWN!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W114^N^5^N^5.1.2^N^6940^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H57361-2^N^PACKOFF,MS-700, 18.750 X 16.000,WEIGHT SET, 6500 PSI MWP F/17.50 BIT. WEIGHT: 126 LBS. (EST.)^N^5153.57^N^Y^N^USD^N^5153.57^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^16" Packoff!@!<<BLT>> 6.5/4 KSI MWP(above/below)!@!<<BLT>> Weight set!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^^N^^N^W115^N^5^N^5.3^N^126^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^EA###DB-1950^N^1.) PRINT SALES ORDER (COS); 2.) CERTIFICATE OF CONFORMANCE. (COC); 3.) ASSY AND/OR COMPONENTS TRACE SHEET(S).; 4.) MATERIAL TEST REPORTS (MTR).; 5.) FACTORY ACCEPTANCE TEST REPORTS (FAT) WITH CHARTS, FOR ASSEMBLIES ONLY. NOTE: (API-6A PSL3 REQUIREDDOCUMENTATION PLUS MTR'S.)^N^212.5^N^Y^N^USD^N^212.5^N^0.0^N^0.0^N^0.0^N^0.0^N^1^N^1^N^No^N^$^$^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^<<BLT>> Charge to pull and compile material certs for SSWE per Vetco Gray standard Quality Code 1950. Documentation Specialist will be responsible for reviewing documentation and compiling electronic data books!@!<<BLT>> Electronic Data Book to Include: Sales Order, C of C, Trace Sheets, MTRs, Dimensional Reports (as applicable), Hardness Reports (as applicable), NDE Reports (as applicable) FAT Reports (for assemblies only)!@!and Heat Treatment Records (as applicable).!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!^N^Empty^N^No^N^W116^N^10^N^10^N^^N^0.0^N^^N^false###H56336-2^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^^N^^N^W117^N^11^N^11.2^N^6547^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H56345-1^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^^N^^N^W118^N^11^N^11.2^N^4812^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H225636-1^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^^N^^N^W119^N^11^N^11.2^N^4377^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H128389-1^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^^N^^N^W120^N^11^N^11.2^N^610^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H30258^N^TOOL-SC&P PART, TORQUE TOOL, TOP RETAINER RING, 30", FOR REMOTE RELEASE JOINT^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^TOOL-SC&P PART, TORQUE TOOL, TOP RETAINER RING, 30", FOR REMOTE RELEASE JOINT^N^^N^^N^W121^N^11^N^11.2^N^280^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^###H224492-14^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^0.0^N^Y^N^USD^N^0.0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^0^N^1^N^1^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^TOOL-SSWE PART,RUNNING,RAM^N^^N^^N^W122^N^11^N^11.2^N^1910^N^0.0^N^^N^false^N^^N^^N^^N^0.0^N^^N^Charge to pull and compile material certs for SSWE per Vetco Gray standard Quality Code 1950. Documentation Specialist will be responsible for reviewing documentation and compiling electronic data books!@!<<BLT>> Electronic Data Book to Include: Sales Order, C of C, Trace Sheets, MTRs, Dimensional Reports (as applicable), Hardness Reports (as applicable), NDE Reports (as applicable) FAT Reports (for assemblies only) and Heat Treatment Records!@!(as applicable).!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!!@!
```

Comment: Yes there are errors.Probably in your code.Put some code here

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: The order of equal elements is not being preserved. After the first pass, 9.1 is before 4.1, but after the second pass, the order is not preserved and 4.1 ends up before 9.1. On the second pass, 5.1.2 is before 5.3, but on the third pass, 5.3 ends up before 5.1.2.

Comment: The complexity here is that I have the values in the form X.X.X, X.X, X, not in the form X.X.0 or X.0.0 which makes it difficult. I am also a little confused about preserving the order of equal elements.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not a radix sort. It's some type of swapping sort that is swapping non-adjacent elements, which could be why the order of equal elements is not preserved. The code is similar to insertion sort, but not quite. Change the code to insertion sort and it should be OK. Look at the two pseudo code examples in this wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

The second pseudo code example is a bit faster.